# asp.net Button - URL includes The Request.Querying string

Tags: asp.net

I have a Button and I am trying to include query string from the URL, but I couldn't get it to work.

Please help.

```
<asp:Button ID="myBtn" runat="server" Text="Upload Company/Contact" CssClass="button3" 
                    OnClientClick="window.parent.location.href='/Apps/ERP/ASPX/UploadContact/UploadContact.aspx?RefNum=" + <%# Request.QueryString["RefNum"]%>'; return false;" />
```

Comment: Set the value from the code behind.

Comment: why are you using window.parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%#` is for binding, `%=` is for setting.  In this case, you need to set the value.

I'd also change the calculation to do a string concatenation:

```
<asp:Button ID="myBtn" runat="server" 
         Text="Upload Company/Contact" CssClass="button3"
      OnClientClick='<%= "window.parent.location.href='/Apps/ERP/ASPX/UploadContact/UploadContact.aspx?RefNum=" + Request.QueryString["RefNum"] + "';return false;" %>' />
```

And like @MikeSmithDev said, you can set this in the code behind, such as Page_Load:

```
myBtn.OnClientClick = "window.parent.location.href='/Apps/ERP/ASPX/UploadContact/UploadContact.aspx?RefNum=" + 
                        Request.QueryString["RefNum"] + "';return false;";
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried your suggestion: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: Really?  That is basic stuff.  I just noticed you are using C#, so I've updated the example.

Comment: Your first string concatenation is not working.  Yes, the method MikeSmithDev suggested is working.  Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Just Check it out following url, Very well explain server tag.
http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx

In your case ps2goat is right, you are trying to set Server Side code in Client Side, You need to use `'<%=  %>'` syntax.
Let me know if u need any further help.